# How to make service configurations in Eclipse Hono deployed on a K8s cluster?

Tags: eclipse-hono

I have deployed Hono on a K8s cluster using helm chart following the documentation from [here](https://github.com/eclipse/packages/tree/master/charts/hono). I am able to make some basic configuration changes using the values.yaml file. But I can't find where and how to configure service configurations of components like adapters, device registry, vertx options, etc when the deployment is on K8s cluster. Is it even possible to make these configuration changes post deployment using helm chart? or do I need to make the changes in source code, build, publish docker images and then deploy on K8s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service configurations of adapters and device registry can be configured using `values.yaml`. For example, the service configurations for HTTP adapter defined [here](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/admin-guide/http-adapter-config/) can be configured using the `values.yaml` as in the below example.

```
adapters:
   http:
      hono:
        app:
          maxInstances: 1
        http:
          authenticationRequired: false
```